# Prove that if $g = r +ip$ is analytic on $C$ and $r(x,y) \leq M$, with $M > 0$, for all $(x,y)\in C$, $g$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $g = r +ip$ be analytic on $C$.

If for some $M > 0$ we have $r(x,y) \leq M$ for all of $C$, then $g$ is constant.

The theorem is given without proof in my notes and I can't find any examples that is it applied to.

Can anybody help me understand its significance or prove it?

Comment: This is equivalent to Liouville's theorem: If $\Re g(z)\le M$ for all $z$, then $\left|\frac1{M+1-g(z)}\right|\le1$ for all $z$ and is constant by Liouville.